# Convert MATLAB type: from complex double to double

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, double, complex-numbers

I got a vector of type double let's say **vec**. When I perform for instance

```
  test=vec.^ 1.4623;
```

I end up with **test** as **complex double** type, and I am wondering if there is a way to convert **test** to **double** since I'd like to get decimal values.
ps: *It's worth highligthing that I am not interested in real numbers retrieved from:*

```
 real(test)
```

As an illustration:

```
vec(2)^1.4623 = -1.8293^1.4623 =  -2.4185
```

but instead i got:

```
test(2)=vec(2)^1.4623= -0.285678007027767 - 2.40147255196906i
```

In a nutshell, a way of converting:

```
test(2) = -2.4185
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily "remove" the minus sign, which causes the complex numbers:

```
vec = [-2.5, 2, -1.5 , 1, -0.5, 0];
sign_vec = sign(vec);
test = sign_vec.*((sign_vec.*vec).^1.4623);
```

This results in:

```
test =
      -3.8186    2.7555   -1.8092    1.0000   -0.3629         0
```

A generic way of your conversion involves the `abs` function:

```
>> test = (-1.8293)^1.4623
test = 
      -0.2858 - 2.4015i

>> -abs(test)
ans =
     -2.4185
```